# How to change table row ID dynamically based on the row delete?

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 5 rows, My requirement is to add/delete table row dynamically..at the same time to handle the table row id dynamically.

Please find my table here:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr id='1'>
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='2'>
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='3'>
        <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='4'>
        <td>Row 4</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr id='5'>
        <td>Row 5</td>    
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am using jquery below code for deletion. For ex. I am deleting second row, then the row id 2 has been deleted and row id should be interchange dynamically.

Find my script here:

```
var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
if (index > 0) {
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Don't use incremental `id` attributes. It always ends up being a maintenance nightmare - like this. If you can you explain why you need the `id` attributes, I'm sure someone here will be able to offer you a much more suitable solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Is there any approach for this problem comes to your mind? Please share it. it will be useful for many :)

Comment: @Murali pinning the logic to a specific element using `this` and then traversing the DOM from there is always a better solution. However it is completely dependant on the logic required and the HTML structure. Without seeing those it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Fiddel Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HjZkB/2/)**

use `nextAll` method to select all next element .. to change the id .it works `effectively`

```
 $("tr").click(function () {
        $(this).nextAll().each(function () {
            var id = $(this).prop("id", function (index, idvalue) {
            return idvalue - 1;
           });
      });
        $(this).remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the ids of all the rows while you removing anyone,

```
if (index > 0) {
 var cache = $(this).closest('tbody');
 $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 cache.find('tr').attr('id',function(i){ return (i + 1) }); 
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wUZwS/)

Comment: @reigel Thanks..! it was a typo...!